# Could somebody help fill in these blanks

Tags: grammar

这个汤`_______`么`_______`么酸啊？ 我可喝不`_______`？

There is no context for these fill in the blanks. I do have a few more, but this was the hardest question because my initial guess is that its the grammar pattern 要么。。。要么。。。, but the words are too close together.

Comment: Here's one possibility: 这个汤 **为什** 么 **这** 么酸啊？ 我可喝不 **可喝** ？Do you have any follow-up questions?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this site was about contributing to the community at large. Next time I'll remember. However, this question specifically says to use one word answers for each blank, which is why I was so confused.

Comment: You mean use the same word for each blank? Does that question specify how many characters should the word have? Hmm, I feel difficult to find one ... even I'm a native speaker ...

Comment: Try `怎`, `那`, `得`. Is this your homework?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow "这个汤[那]么[那]么酸啊？" makes sense (the scene is "you hear some one describes how sour some soup is, and then you say 那么那么 or 这么这么 to marvel at that".), but "我可喝不[那]？" doesn't make sense.

Comment: “这个汤[怎]么[这/那]么酸啊？我可喝不[下/了]。” sounds very natural in Northern China, and is very likely the answer. I am not sure about how natural/common this expression is in Southern China, @Stan may be able to comment.

Comment: @NS.X. one snag though; the second sentence ends with a question mark, which means 下/了 don't quite fit.

Comment: @NS.X. Natural in Southern China too. But OP's comment above says **"this question specifically says to use one word answers for each blank"**. I'm not sure if OP means the same word for each blank.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be a homework question that is too localized and is unlikely to be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

这个汤怎么这么酸啊？我可喝不下。 
But I'm wondering why there is a question mark in the end. This doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

这个汤怎么这/那么酸啊？我可喝不下。is correct;

这个汤怎么这/那么酸啊？我可喝不了(liao)。is also correct but is more common in north China.

这个汤怎么这/那么酸啊？我可喝不得。I can understand, but it seems nobody talk like this.

这么 and 那么 have similar meaning in this sentence

This sentence means "the soup is too sour to drink"

Usage of 要么……要么……：他这么开心，要么中奖了，要么升职了 it is kind of guessing with two possible choices

Answer (score 0):

> 这个汤_**_***么***_**_么酸啊？

1）怎
2）这/那（both of them are right, we Chinese usually use them to enhance the depth of something as an adverb).

> 我可喝不_**__**？

Don't write anything here, ……不=……吗, meaning a question to ask others. 
e.g:
他是好人，可不？(He's a right man, isn't he?!)

PS: According to the meaning of the part of the sentence, I guess “？”should be "。", because the author wanna say **this soup is too sour for him to have**.